# Solaris file permissions not inherited by OAG log files

Tags: permissions, solaris, chmod, acl

OS: Oracle Solaris 11.3 SPARC

Issue: I'm trying to inherit file permissions using ACL and it's partially working. For the files and directories I create on my own in the shell permissions are inherited, on the other hand OAG (Oracle Api Gateway) while creating log files in that directory (being the same user and having the same group) does not inherit it = uses default ones.

Command that I am using:

```
/usr/bin/chmod A=owner@:full_set:fd:allow,group@:read_set:fd:allow,everyone@:full_set:fd:deny trace/
```

Basically I want the logs which are being created by OAG to inherit trace folder permissions: all for owner, read for group and none for everyone else.

Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Memory is that you have to set the setgid bit on the directory.